# EmguCV capture frames QueryFrame()

Tags: emgucv

I'm using emgu cv 3.0.0 and I would like to capture frames from a USB cam. 
Unfortunately, I get an error while calling `Image<Bgr, Byte> image = capture.QueryFrame();`
It says, I can't convert from `Emgu.CV.Mat` to `Emgu.CV.Image`.

Answer (score 7):

Try this line of code

```
Image<Bgr, Byte> image = capture.QueryFrame().ToImage<Bgr,Byte>();
```

Answer (score 3):

In cv v 3.0.0 most methods use Mat for image representation. 
You can try this to get the frame from the camera:

```
Mat frame = new Mat();
_capture.Retrieve(frame, 0);
```

For conversion to gray:

```
Mat grayFrame = new Mat();
CvInvoke.CvtColor(frame, grayFrame, ColorConversion.Bgr2Gray);
```

Also you can see how it works in examples [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/emguexample/).

Comment: Thank you! Works fine ;)